# What is going on with the stack pointer in this simple (disassembled) C program?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

By way of learning more about assembly language / computer architecture, I wrote the following C code:

```
int my_caller() {
    int a = my_callee(0xbaba);
    return a;
}

int my_callee(int a) {
    return a;
}
```

This disassembles (on my machine; with some added comments) to the following:

```
; my_caller function
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
sub esp,byte +0x18
sub esp,byte +0xc
push dword 0xbaba
call dword 0x1e
add esp,byte +0x10
mov [ebp-0xc],eax
mov eax,[ebp-0xc]
leave
ret

; my_callee function
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,[ebp+0x8]
pop ebp
ret
```

Regarding treatment of `esp` in `my_caller`:

1. Why do we `sub esp` by 0x18 and then 0xc; why not just a single sub of 0x24?
2. After returning from `my_callee`, what is the point of `add esp,byte 0x10`? The `leave` instruction is going to annul this anyway with the implicit `mov esp,ebp`.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization.

Comment: Compilers generate *good* code but not necessarily the *best* code, with or without optimization.  Two consecutive `sub esp` instructions, for example, might be generated because they were generated for two different reasons.  The code that you see is managing the "stack frame" and the parameters and local-variables.  "Every language is different" as to how it does this.  This is one reason why it can be tricky to call libraries, or to mix languages in a single project.

Comment: depends on the compiler (and its version) and command line options for starters.  If gcc for example it may make perfect sense when looking at the code.  there may be one adjustment in one place for one thing and another for another reason and those being somewhere the peephole optimizer cant reach.  Or you are not using a compiler with any optimization, even peephole....

Comment: no reason to assume a compiler makes the perfect code every time.  they are far more efficient over large projects than a human, but there is almost always somewhere that a human can fix/tweak something the compiler missed.

Answer (score 2):

You told the compiler you'd like it to compile fast, not to make good code, and to make code that was easy for a debugger like `gdb` to interact with.  In `-O0` mode, gcc doesn't optimize much between different parts of the same function, hence the `add esp, 0x10` to pop the stack after the call, and then `leave` separately.

`-O0` is terribly noisy (full of stores/reloads), so it sucks to read as a human.

You'll have better luck looking at functions that take a couple `int` args and return an `int`.  You can use `__attribute__((noinline))` on functions to stop them from inlining.

Have a look at a simple function on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-xc+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell++-fno-tree-vectorize',source:'//+function+with+an+input+and+an+output,+so+it+doesn!'t+optimize+away+to+returning+a+constant%0Aint+foo(int+n)+%7B%0A++int+factorial+%3D+1%3B%0A++for+(int+i%3D1+%3B+i+%3C+n+%3B+i%2B%2B+)%0A++++factorial+*%3D+i%3B%0A++return+factorial%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), for example.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.